transferring a value in Flask without the need to propagate it via args
I am currently building a web application on top of an already existing python app, and I am doing it in a client server architecture
So I introduced Flask into the app as a REST server, in this case, I have to pass a token to the server, which the server then uses to authenticate to Azure DevOps
The issue is that I need to pass this token from
authHeader = request.headers.get('PAT')

To whatever function that needs it, and doing so via propagating it's as argument will take forever for each individual case since there are many higher order functions in the way
So I was wondering if there is any cleaner way to do this while keeping each function call confined to the request context it's called in
I did try to use flask.g which didn't pass through my value to where it needs to be

It hard to advise without seeing any of the structure of your code or what you have already tried with the g object.
